# How do I resolve -Java Wrapper Class Error

Tags: java

Using Eclipse Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)
Trying to print the following

```
package Hello_World;

public class WrapperTypes {
    
    public static void main (String[]args) {
                
        int myInt =10;
        Integer myInteger = new Integer( value: 10);
        Integer myInteger2=20; 
        Integer myInteger3=Integer.valueOf(10);
        Integer myInteger4=Integer.parseInt(s: "3"); 
        Integer myInteger5=null;  
                
        System.out.println("myInteger= " + myInteger);
        System.out.println("myInteger2= " + myInteger2);
        System.out.println("myInteger3= " + myInteger3);
        System.out.println("myInteger4= " + myInteger4);
        System.out.println("myInteger5= " + myInteger5);
        System.out.println("myInteger= " + myInteger);
        
    }
    

}
```

Error

> value cannot be resolved to a variable    - Syntax error on token ":",
> invalid AssignmentOperator

If code is executed error is
"value cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: `new Integer( value: 10);`  is not valid Java.  Java doesn't support Python style  "keyword" arguments.

Comment: It is also worth noting that your program won't show anything interesting.  All of the printlns will end up displaying the value of the respective `Integer` object, no matter how it is created.  If you want to observe the different behavior of autoboxing versus `new` etcetera, you need to compare object references using `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% what you're going for here, but change

```
 Integer myInteger = new Integer( value: 10);
```

to

```
Integer myInteger = new Integer(10);
```

and

```
Integer myInteger4=Integer.parseInt(s: "3");
```

to

```
Integer myInteger4=Integer.parseInt("3");
```

Final code as

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    int myInt =10;
    Integer myInteger = new Integer(10);
    Integer myInteger2=20; 
    Integer myInteger3=Integer.valueOf(10);
    Integer myInteger4=Integer.parseInt("3"); 
    Integer myInteger5=null;  
            
    System.out.println("myInteger= " + myInteger);
    System.out.println("myInteger2= " + myInteger2);
    System.out.println("myInteger3= " + myInteger3);
    System.out.println("myInteger4= " + myInteger4);
    System.out.println("myInteger5= " + myInteger5);
    System.out.println("myInteger= " + myInteger);
}
```